# I was meeting a lot of people while I was working in London. I met a lot of people while I was working in London

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, differences

I was meeting a lot of people while I was working in London. 
I met a lot of people while I was working in London. 
What is the difference between them? 
I'm not sure about these sentences. 
How to clear them? 
Please, explain it easily.

Answer (score 2):

I met a lot of people while I was working in London. - The focus here is on "a lot of people" and that's what you'd say normally now that you don't live there anymore.

I was meeting a lot of people while I was working in London. - You wouldn't say "I was meeting" unless you add something more such as, *everyday* or *every weekend* to it. The emphasis is on the frequency of meetings. *Past continuous* is used to refer to the continuity or frequency of an action.

Comment: "I was meeting..." would only be used when being mildly racist, satirising the speech of an Indian visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Sankarane is right. To provide the first clause a sense of continuity you may write "I HAPPENED TO MEET/ I USED TO MEET" but cannot make it past continuous as well.